# Construct a hash with other hashes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join, hash

I want to join 2 or more hashes like this.

```
h1 = { :es => { :hello  => "You" } }
h2 = { :es => { :bye => "Man" } }
```

How can I get this?

```
h1 + h2 = { :es => { :hello => "you", :bye => "Man" } }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the merge to be recursive? E.g. what if you had: `{:es => {:abc => {:child_1 => 1}}}` and `{:es => {:abc => {:child_2 => 2}}}` ? Do you want `{:es => {:abc => {:child_1 => 1, :child_2 => 2}}}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the deep_merge method. Does exactly what you want.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > {:es => {:hello => "You" } }.deep_merge({:es => {:bye => "Man"}})
=> {:es=>{:hello=>"You", :bye=>"Man"}}
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/DeepMerge/deep_merge

Comment: Note, you need to require activesupport for this.

Comment: Yes. I found the same solution. I am using deep_merge in rails. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
irb(main):001:0> h1 = {:es => {:hello => "You"}}
=> {:es=>{:hello=>"You"}}
irb(main):002:0> h2 = {:es => {:bye => "Man"}}
=> {:es=>{:bye=>"Man"}}
irb(main):003:0> h1.each_key {|x| h1[x].merge! h2[x]}
=> {:es=>{:bye=>"Man", :hello=>"You"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to activesupport's [deep_merge](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge!), but with a functional approach. Works recursively:

```
class Hash
  def inner_merge(other_hash)
    other_hash.inject(self) do |acc, (key, value)|
      if (acc_value = acc[key]) && acc_value.is_a?(Hash) && value.is_a?(Hash)
        acc.merge(key => acc_value.inner_merge(value))
      else
        acc.merge(key => value)
      end
    end       
  end
end

h1.inner_merge(h2) #=> {:es=>{:hello=>"You", :bye=>"Man"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use ActiveSupport, this Proc will perform a deep merge.  1.8.7 & 1.9.2 compatible.

```
dm = lambda {|l,r| l.merge(r) {|k,ov,nv| l[k] = ov.is_a?(Hash) ? dm[ov, nv || {}] : nv} }
dm[h1,h2]
#  => {:es=>{:hello=>"You", :bye=>"Man"}}
```